# Throwing errors to users from Community Connector

Tags: looker-studio

I've followed the guide at https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling#non-admin-messages for handing back an error to the users from the getData method. However, even when using the provided example method to throw an error to the user, I still get the generic error on all my reports:

Logging Method:

```
/**
   * Throws an error that complies with the community connector spec.
   * @param {string} message The error message.
   * @param {boolean} userSafe Determines whether this message is safe to show
   *     to non-admin users of the connector. true to show the message, false
   *     otherwise. false by default.
   */
  function throwConnectorError(message, userSafe) {
    userSafe = (typeof userSafe !== 'undefined' &&
                typeof userSafe === 'boolean') ?  userSafe : false;
    if (userSafe) {
      message = 'DS_USER:' + message;
    }

    throw new Error(message);
  }
```

Calling Code:

```
try{
    //SOME CODE HERE THAT THROWS ERROR
}catch (ex){
    logConnectorError("getData: Unexpected Error:", ex);
    if (ex.message !== null){    
      throwConnectorError("Unable to fetch data due to server error: " + ex.message, true);
    }
    else{
      throwConnectorError("Unexpected error: " + ex, true);
    }
  }
```

Error when running:

```
Error Details
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Error ID: 0e1e80fb
```

Is this system still working or is there an example working connector I can view to see if there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at some of our Open Source Community Connectors like the [npm Downloads Connector](https://github.com/google/datastudio/tree/master/community-connectors/npm-downloads) and the [Stack Overflow Questions Connector](https://github.com/google/datastudio/tree/master/community-connectors/stackoverflow-questions) to see examples of error handling. Make sure that your [`isAdminUser()`](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#isadminuser) function is returning `true` for the tester unless the error messages won't be shown. The error handling is mostly geared towards `getData()`. For now, it might not work as desired for other required functions.